# SwiftData syntax error in SELECT COUNT(*) or incorrect optimization?

Tags: swift-data

I want to count the number of models that match my filters (Predicate). To do this, I don't need all the fields of the Item model, but only the Information field. Therefore, I add propertiesToFetch to optimize (?). Most likely, this is unnecessary with context.fetchCount, but the error is reproduced when I configure a similar descriptor for Query.

Code to reproduce:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftData

struct Information: Codable, Hashable {
  var field: Int
  var field2: Double
  var field3: Date
  
  init() {
    self.field = 0
    self.field2 = 0.0
    self.field3 = Date()
  }
}

@Model
class Item {
  @Attribute(.unique) let id: UUID
  
  var information: Information
  
  init() {
    self.id = UUID()
    self.information = Information()
  }
  
  
  static func count(context: ModelContext) -> Int {
    var descriptor = FetchDescriptor<Item>()
    
    descriptor.propertiesToFetch = [\.information]
    
    do {
      return try context.fetchCount(descriptor)
    } catch {
      return 0
    }
    
  }
}


struct ContentView: View {
  @Environment(\.modelContext) var context
  
  @State private var count: Int = 0
  var body: some View {
    Text("\(count)")
      .onAppear {
        count = Item.count(context: context)
      }
  }
}
```

I want to see the number of created models, now it is 0, and I am getting a huge number and an error in the console:

error: (1) I/O error for database at ... near ".": syntax error in "SELECT COUNT(*) from (SELECT t0.ZFIELDt0.ZFIELD2t0.ZFIELD3 FROM ZITEM t0 )"

If I remove the descriptor.propertiesToFetch = [.information], there are no problems. In the context of counting the number of models, this may not be important, but in Query I would like to leave it for optimization.

Comment: How is it optimisation to use `propertiesToFetch` when counting? The fetch will return an integer representing the number of objects (and the sql query will do the same) so `propertiesToFetch` has nothing to do with performance here. Besides that, from the error you got in the console it looks like `propertiesToFetch` is buggy or doesn't work when used with fetchCount. So all in all forget about `propertiesToFetch` when using `fetchCount`

Comment: I'm not talking only about fetchCount, the same error is also with Query(descriptor)

Comment: I see that now when I re-read your question but it wasn’t obvious the first time I read it. So I guess we have another SwiftData bug then.